# Unable to bind to async loaded array - Knockout

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js, binding

I have a model that I'm trying to load an `observableArray`, but for some reason the binding isn't working. If I put items into the array where the model is defined it will bind, but if I do an `ajax` call to load items, they won't be bound. What is the best way to go about loading items asynchronously? Here is the model:

```
 function Clinic() {

var self = this;

self.searchType = ko.observable();
self.clinicName = ko.observable();
self.providerSpecialty = ko.observable();
self.address = ko.observable();
self.city = ko.observable();
self.county = ko.observable();
self.state = ko.observable();
self.network = ko.observable();
self.zip = ko.observable();
self.searchDistance = ko.observable("10");
self.nameSearchType = ko.observable();

self.cityOptions = ko.observableArray(['City a', 'city b', 'city c']);
self.countyOptions = ko.observableArray(['Ada, ID', 'Adair, IA', 'Adams, ND']);
self.stateOptions = ko.observableArray(['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'NV', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV']);
self.nameSearchTypeOptions = ko.observableArray(['Starts With', 'Contains']);

self.specialties = ko.observableArray();

self.nextButtonEnable = ko.computed(function () {

    return typeof this.searchType() === "undefined" ? false : true;

}, self);
```

}

I'm trying to load `self.specialties` without any luck. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 loadSpecialties: function () {



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "clinic-search.aspx/GetAllSpecialties",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $(data.d).each(function (i, e) {
                        vm.clinic().specialties().push(e.Description);
                    });
                });

            },
```

I'm calling `vm.loadSpecialties()` before doing `ko.appliBindings(vm)`, but the items don't get bound. I even wrote a function to check if something is in the array, and it's telling me there is 140 items.

```
 checkSpecialties: function () {
                alert("length: " + vm.clinic().specialties().length);
                alert("first: " + vm.clinic().specialties()[0]);
            },
```

Here is the HTML that I'm trying to bind to. Like I said before it will work if I hard-code items into the specialties array, but it won't work with an ajax call. Any ideas?

```
 <div id="Name" data-bind="with: clinic, visible: showName">
            <div>
                <p>Name options...</p>
                <div>
                    <p class="bold">Enter all or part of the clinic name.</p>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: clinicName" />
                        <select data-bind="options: nameSearchTypeOptions, value: nameSearchType"></select>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <p class="bold">Select a provider specialty, if one is preferred.</p>
                    <select data-bind="options: specialties, value: providerSpecialty"></select>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Start Over" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parent.startOver" />
                <input type="button" value="check specialties" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parent.checkSpecialties" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating the underlying array that is observed but you're not notifying any subscribers.

The simplest thing you can do to fix this is to push into the observable array, not the underlying array.  Or if you want to minimize the notifications, insert into the underlying array (as you have it) but notify the subscribers manually by calling `valueHasMutated()` in the end.

```
$(data.d).each(function (i, e) {
    // note: not invoking specialties
    vm.clinic().specialties.push(e.Description);
});

// or
$(data.d).each(function (i, e) {
    vm.clinic().specialties().push(e.Description);
});
vm.clinic().specialties.valueHasMutated();
```

However in general, when loading up values into an observable array, I think it would be better to load the values into a new array then set the array into the observable.

```
vm.clinic().specialties(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(data.d, function (e) {
        return e.Description;
    })
);
```